# Extract Text from PDF file :It Sometimes Omits Important Marker

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, pypdf

I am dealing with WTO panel report file, and the pdf used below is linked here: https://docs.wto.org/dol2fe/Pages/FE_Search/FE_S_S006.aspx?Query=(%40Symbol%3d+wt%2fds2%2f*)&Language=ENGLISH&Context=FomerScriptedSearch&languageUIChanged=true#

If I use PyPDF2:

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('/Users/zachary/Downloads/2R.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(1)
page_content = page.extractText()
print(page_content)
```

It returns good results however without white-spaces between words

**TableofContentsI.INTRODUCTION....................................1II.FACTUALASPECTS....................................2A.TheCleanAirAct..................................3B.EPA'sGasolineRule................................31.EstablishmentofBaselines........................32.ReformulatedGasoline..........................43.ConventionalGasoline(or"Anti-DumpingRules")........4C.TheMay1994Proposal..............................5III.MAINARGUMENTS....................................5A.General....................................5B.TheGeneralAgreementonTariffsandTrade................61.ArticleI-GeneralMost-Favoured-NationTreatment.......62.ArticleIII-NationalTreatmentonInternalTaxationandRegulation...............................7a)ArticleIII:4............................7b)ArticleIII:1............................143.ArticleXX-GeneralExceptions....................154.ArticleXX(b)................................15a)"ProtectionofHuman,AnimalandPlantLifeorHealth".............................15b)"Necessary"............................155.ArticleXX(d)................................216.ArticleXX(g)................................22a)"Relatedtotheconservationofexhaustiblenaturalresources..."............................22b)"...madeeffectiveinconjunctionwithrestrictionsondomesticproductionorconsumption"..........237.PreambletoArticleXX..........................238.ArticleXXIII-NullificationandImpairment............25**

What is important to me is each "Roman" character(I. Introduction II.Factual Aspect III.Main Arguments) that located at the Table of Contents' page. I will parse the pages with reference to this page markers.

Also, If I use the module textract:

```
text = textract.process('/Users/zachary/Downloads/{}R.pdf'.format(i), method ='pdfminer' )#import text file

text = str(text)

text
```

**b'WORLD TRADE\n\nORGANIZATION\n\nRESTRICTED\n\nWT/DS2/R\n29 January 1996\n\n(96-0326)\n\nUnited States -\n\nStandards for Reformulated\n\nand Conventional Gasoline\n\nReport of the Panel\n\n\x0cTable of Contents\n\nI.\n\nII.\n\nINTRODUCTION\n\n. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nFACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nA.\n\nB.\n\nThe Clean Air Act . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nEPA\'s Gasoline Rule . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\n1.\n\n2.\n\n3.\n\nEstablishment of Baselines . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nReformulated Gasoline . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nConventional Gasoline (or "Anti-Dumping Rules")\n\n. . . . . . . .\n\nC.\n\nThe May 1994 Proposal\n\n. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nIII. MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nA.\n\nB.\n\nGeneral\n\n. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nThe General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\n1.\n\n2.\n\n3.\n\n4.\n\n5.\n\n6.\n\n7.\n\n8.\n\nArticle I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment\n\n. . . . . . .\n\nArticle III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation\nand Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\na)\n\nb)\n\nArticle III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nArticle III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nArticle XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\n\nArticle XX(b)\n\n. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .**

As you can see at the textract one, there's no II. in front of factual aspect.

It just gone!!

What can I do to solve this problem and achieve two goals - 1) Let the Roman Markers Survive 2)But still let the white spaces are well inserted.

Share me some valuable advice to proceed.

Thx

Comment: Please give a try to pdfminer library in Python and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to consider solutions other than PyPDF, check out pdftotext. Compared to PyPDF, I've had better luck with pdftotext. You could also try PDFMiner but I've gotten mixed results with it.

If you're willing to pay, ABBYY makes good software for this, but it is expensive.